# How do I restore unattended-upgrades default settings and conf files in 19.04?

Tags: 19.04

Anyone know how to do the above? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling the package (`purge` then `install` it again) seem to do the desired action— it will overwrite current configuration file (e.g. `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d)/50unattended-upgrade` to the default value.

```
sudo apt purge unattended-upgrades && sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

Tested on 18.04 machine.